# Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have joint p.d.f.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have joint p.d.f.

$$ f(x, y) = 3x, \; 0 < y < x < 1.$$

Find $f_X(x)$,the marginal p.d.f. of $X$.

this is what i got

$$f_X(x) = \int_0^x f(x, y)dy = \int_0^x 3x dy = 3x^2$$
for $0 < x < 1$.

however, if want to know whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not, how can I do it?

Comment: "...want to know is it independent..." Are you interested in the question wether $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: oh yes, sorry my mistakes. that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f(x, y) = fX(x)fY(y) since you already get the fx(X), find fy(y) and then verify, if fx(x)fy(y) is the same withf(x,y) then they are independent.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

The pdf takes value $0$ on $\{\langle x,y\rangle\mid x<y\}$ so that $P(X<Y)=0$.

Then $P(X<c\wedge Y>c)=0$ for each $c$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are indeed independent then:  $$P(X<c\wedge Y>c)=P(X<c)P(Y>c)$$
for each $c$.

So to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are *not* independent it is enough to find some $c$ with: $$P(X<c)P(Y>c)>0$$